# How to add an image to ArCore in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, augmented-reality, arcore, dart-pub

Basically, I have an ar app using the ARCore plugin. I want to add an image to it by placing it at a certain vector. However, the stuff I've seen examples with don't cover this anywhere. So I went to the documentation and found an image class (Link below). However, I don't understand what I need to put in each field as it says bytes and hash and I'm not even sure it this is the correct class. If someone could help with this, that would be amazing!

Links:
Main Page: https://pub.dev/packages/arcore_flutter_plugin

Main Docs:
https://pub.dev/documentation/arcore_flutter_plugin/latest/arcore_flutter_plugin/arcore_flutter_plugin-library.html

ARCore Image Class:
https://pub.dev/documentation/arcore_flutter_plugin/latest/arcore_flutter_plugin/ArCoreImage-class.html

Answer (score 0):

Heyy, you can insert image like this

```
import 'package:arcore_flutter_plugin/arcore_flutter_plugin.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(HelloWorld());
}

class HelloWorld extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HelloWorldState createState() => _HelloWorldState();
}

class _HelloWorldState extends State<HelloWorld> {
  late ArCoreController arCoreController;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Hello World'),
        ),
        body: ArCoreView(
          onArCoreViewCreated: _onArCoreViewCreated,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onArCoreViewCreated(ArCoreController controller) {
    arCoreController = controller;
    _addImage(arCoreController);
  }

  Future<Uint8List> getImageBytes(String imageName) async {
    final ByteData data = await rootBundle.load('assets/$imageName');
    return data.buffer.asUint8List();
  }

  void _addImage(ArCoreController controller) async {
    final imagebytes = await getImageBytes("harry.png");
    final node = ArCoreNode(
      image:ArCoreImage(bytes:imagebytes,width:50,height:50),
      position: vector.Vector3(-0.5, 0.5, -3.5),
    );
    controller.addArCoreNode(node);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    arCoreController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).